# Ошибка "object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, http, requests

Мне нужно достать параметр "intelligence" у 3-героев, написал код, думал по ключам пройдусь до нужного уровня вложенности и добавлю нужные значения в новый словарь, но мне выдает ошибку "object is not subscriptable", при попытке пройтись по ключам, хотя я проверял через 'type' - объектом является словарь! В чем может быть причина?

```
from pprint import pprint

import requests

import json
superheroes = {}

TOKEN = '2619421814940190'

API = "https://superheroapi.com/api/2619421814940190/"

hero_list = {'Hulk', 'Captain America', 'Thanos'}

for name in hero_list:
    responses = requests.get(API + f'/search/{name}')
    x = responses['results']['powerstats']['intelligence']
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался, в строку x = response[......] после response надо добавить .json()

Answer (score 3):

Берите из ответа `json()`, ну и циклами по нему идите:

```
for result in requests.get(API + f'/search/{name}').json()['results']:
    print(name, result['powerstats']['intelligence'])
```

Вывод:

```
Hulk 88
Hulk 50
Hulk 81
Captain America 69
Thanos 100
```

Для `Hulk` там список из нескольких результатов, почему так - я не знаю, такая структура у возвращаемого `json`-а.

Answer (score 1):

Вставляем отладочную печать:

```
print(type(responses))
```

после присвоения и видим, что *responses*  это **объект**:

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Соответственно, операцию индексации к нему применить ну никак нельзя!